# Fill the diagonal and off diagonal elements of a square matrix using list items

Tags: python, matrix, square, diagonal

Can someone help me with this?

I have a question on filling a square zero matrix(say 4*4). I have written out two lists which contains values that goes into the diagonal and off diagonal elements of the square matrix.

```
mat=  [[0, 0, 0, 0]  
      [0, 0, 0, 0]  
      [0, 0, 0, 0]  
      [0, 0, 0, 0]]

diagonal_elements in a list : - [a,b,c,d]
off_diag_elements in a list : - [e,f,g,h,i,j,l,..]
```

where

```
a = mat(1_1)   
b = mat(2_2)   
e = mat(1_2)    
f = mat(1_3)    
g = mat(1_4)    
h = mat(2_1) etc.. elements respectively.
```

can someone tell me how to append this values accordingly to the matrix?

This is what I have tried so far on this portion.

```
i=4
Hmat=np.zeros((i,i),dtype=float)
print(Hmat)
#print(Hmat.diagonal())                                                                                                                     
for s in P:
    print(s)
    Hmat = np.fill_diagonal(Hmat, float(s))
```

it keeps giving me this error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: What code have you tried writing?

Comment: thank you for reminiding, I have edited my question with a code snippet i used